# Получение координат в C#

Tags: c#, геолокация

Собственно как получить координаты через gps/wifi/ip? В интернете нашёл видео, где пишут что-то типа

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged;
watcher.Start();
private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("lat: {0} long: {1}", e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude));
        }
```

и после запуска программы windows предложил ввести адрес по умолчанию (город, индекс и тп), ввёл, но даже после этого message box не открылся. И ошибок никаких нет

P.S. только недавно начал программировать

Comment: "message box не открылся"... значит PositionChanged не срабатал. "В интернете нашёл видео" - лучше более достоверные ресурсы смотреть https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee808853(v=vs.110).aspx и https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.device.location(v=vs.110).aspx. А еще в windows 10(и в других наверное) в настройках "Местоположение" функция местоопределения может быть отключена.